# Multi-page application using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a multi-page application using angularjs, because i want to make use of a lot of angularjs functionality, like two way binding, form validation, AJAX handling, etc. But I read from some blogs that angularjs is best suited for SPA only. Is that right?

Can I use it in my multi-page application?

If I can use it for a multi-page application, what is the better approach to implement it. Do I need to create a separate controller for each page?

Comment: [Is Angular.js Just for Single Page Applications (SPA)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231251/is-angular-js-just-for-single-page-applications-spa)

Comment: I had use Angular in a web application on some pages, where it was required. It works great.

Comment: Since a web request (non ajax) is a "reset", you have to use separate ng-app.

Comment: in new versions of angular ( >1.5 and angular 2) , you can create isolated components, that are easy to reuse.